# Can we enable auto scrolling down in the chat window when we click on the button of a hero card?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

I have deployed and published my bot in Direct Line channel. When the results obtained are more than one, I will get a series of corresponding results in the form of hero cards. Now when we click on any of the Hero card's button, it will give a response at the bottom. To check the response I need to go all through the down and need to check the response. Here I required, automatic scrolling when we click on the button.

I have found a solution to this:

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
{},
({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY_FULFILLED') {
        document.querySelector('ul[role="list"]').lastChild.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
    }
    return next(action);
}
);

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
store
 }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

The above-shown snippet is working fine by using "IamBack" button activity type but I am using "**PostBack**" to hide the value from the button click. In my case, the above-shown snippet is not working. Please suggest me any changes required.
I am new to bot framework, please suggest me some solution.

Here is code of Hero card with Postback activity type.

```
var heroCard = new ThumbnailCard
        {
            Title = title.ToUpperInvariant(),
            Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(filename) },
            Subtitle = description,
            Text = "",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, title.ToUpperInvariant(), value: youtubeid) },
        };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Web Chat are you using? The above code snippet only works in Web Chat v4.

Comment: Also, which browser and version are you using (in case of a bug)?

Comment: I would add, why not do a carousel of cards that the user can click thru from side to side? Then, whatever the user clicks will be the next response. If you need an example, I can post an answer for you.

Comment: Yes, I am using v4 and I am using in chrome browser with DirectLine channel. I have changed to the carousel cards, by iterating hero cards. But anyhow I want to hide the response after clicking on the button of the hero card. If I tried to hide it Auto scrolling is not working. To hide the button response I am using PostBack activity type.

Comment: I'm unsure of your response...do you have a working solution now or do you still have an issue?

Comment: I am stuck at scrolling down while using PostBack activity type.

Comment: Sending a `PostBack` is not interfering with the auto scroll feature when I test. What is the next activity that occurs? Is there some API call or long running process that is being made that the bot and, subsequently, Web Chat is waiting on to complete?

Comment: Also, when you say you are using v4 Web Chat, can you post the exact version?

Comment: @StevenKanberg Basically, I am using Directline Channel. That PostBack method and Auto scrolling are working in Webchat. But I required to work it in DirectLine channel along with auto-scrolling.

Comment: When you say "PostBack method and Auto scrolling are working in Webchat"...well, Webchat is built using Direct Line. So I don't understand how it's working in Webchat but not in Direct Line. Are you trying to build a custom client using Direct Line? Something other than Webchat?